# How to cancel a JobService

Tags: android

Im tryin to cancel JobService with the class. I have tried to use stopSelf(); when did not work, what am i missing to get this working.

```
public class example extends JobService {
    private boolean Working = false;
    public boolean jobCancel = false;
    private boolean example = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters parameters){
        Working = true;
        runOnThread(parameters);
        jobFinished(parameters, false);

        return Working;
    }

    public void runOnThread(final JobParameters parameters){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                if(example == true){
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include what error message (if any) you are getting and what outcome you would expect

Answer (score 0):

Move your `jobFinished(parameters, false);` statement to where you have your `stopSelf()` call. Then, after that, simply return from your `run()` method.

Comment: after running jobFinish where stopself() is. The run still seems to run again, do I need to do something else to make the run not run again, unless the job is started again

Comment: @Jack: Call `cancel()` or `cancelAll()` on `JobScheduler` to cancel the job and prevent it from running again.